# Capture in Powershell the exitcode of a batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, tortoisesvn

In the script underneath i want to capture the exitcode of the release.bat in order to svn commit if it succesfull. The problem is that the commit is done before the end of the release.bat (which is the build batch for my companys' vb6 client-side). I tried to sleep the procedure but i think is bad programming and the duration of the script is not always the same. So is there any solution to catch the actual exitcode from the script?

```
$strRevisionNumber1 = [string]$null
$timestamp = get-date -f "yyyy-M-d-h-m-s"
$SvnLogPath= Get-Location
$logfile = "${SvnLogPath}svn_dotnet_update_${timestamp}.log"
new-item -type file $logfile | out-null
$lcllogfile = "C:\Users\dimser.DEVELVM\Desktop\BuildAutomationTrunks\dotnet\build\logs.xml"
$dotnettrnk = "C:\Users\dimser.DEVELVM\Desktop\BuildAutomationTrunks\dotnet"
$build = "C:\Users\dimser.DEVELVM\Desktop\BuildAutomationTrunks\dotnet\build\release.bat"

#########################################################################################################################
                                   ##############SCRIPT##############
# ISSUING SVN UPDATE TO EACH DIR"
$dotnettrnk | % {svn update $_ 2>&1 | ft -AutoSize -Wrap | Out-File -Append $logfile } 

#SVN UPDATE VERSION TARGETS
Invoke-Expression "C:\Users\dimser.DEVELVM\Desktop\Scripts\reviseRevNumber.ps1"


# ISSUING SVN LOGS TO LOGS.XML
$dotnettrnk |% {svn log -l 1 -v --xml $_ 2>&1  | ft -AutoSize -Wrap | Out-File $lcllogfile } 

# OPEN LOG FILE AFTER THE COMPLETION
notepad $logfile
notepad $lcllogfile
[xml]$xml = (get-content $lcllogfile)

#STORES THE REVISION NUMBER FOR THE COMMIT
$strRevisionNumber1 = $xml.log.logentry.revision
Write-Host $strRevisionNumber1

$LASTEXITCODE = 1
#CALL THE BUILD SCRIPT
cmd /c $build
Write-host $LASTEXITCODE


#CHECK IF BUILD WAS SUCCESSFUL
if($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0)
{
# ISSUING SVN COMMIT
$dotnettrnk | % {svn commit -m "Build: revision: $strRevisionNumber1" $_ 2>&1 | ft -AutoSize -Wrap | Out-File -Append $logfile }
}
```

Comment: "The problem is that the commit is done before the end of the release.bat" - you can't influence an action that already took place, after the fact.

Comment: I don't know if i put it correctly , as you can see in the code i want to commit the changes after the competion of the batch script, instead of that what is happening is commiting the changes after the start of the script without waiting to end.

Comment: You mean `release.bat` is running something asynchronously in the background?

Comment: Yeah. My powershell scripts ends before the release.bat ends.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Start-Process $build -Wait` instead of `cmd /c $build`.